# Google Calendar "reminders" and Google Keep "reminders"

Tags: google-calendar, reminder

I had the impression that when you create a Calendar reminder, it automatically creates a Google Keep reminder too. This is not the case it seems, after trying it.

However, when I create a reminder through Google Keep, it is automatically shown in calendar.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a Google bug?

Comment: A feature, not a bug. Tasks (i.e. created in keep) can have a location set. When you're 'in' this location then the tasks will show up in your calendar for actioning. I stopped using keep because I could never configure tasks to show up at the right times etc. This may now have changed (hense not putting an answer) as it was years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Per this link, two way reminders between Google Calendar and Google Keep are not completely synchronized.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/NciuZH23Eh4

In Google Keep, Notes which you add a reminder to, automatically make a corresponding reminder in Google Calendar. However, the reverse is not true (yet). which is a little bit of a bummer but good for me to know. (i assumed it was true both directions.)

I just submitted feedback on google calendar. Perhaps they can implement that feature and close the loop.